# how to understand os.environ['JOB_ID'] in python

Tags: python

I have this piece of code from python.

```
if _name_ == '_main_':
   dir, file = os.path.split("myfile.csv")
   out_dir = os.path.join(dir, "myoutput-{0}".format(os.environ['JOB_ID']))
```

I found it is not easy to understand the very last line, especially the `os.environ['JOB_ID']` part. After searching, this may belong to the SGE game engine of python. But I notice that in the python file, there are no statements like "import sge". I am confused. Can anyone please help? Many thanks for your time and attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An environment variable is generally a variable created before python was launched and sort of "passed in", though not explicitly. This is not a python specific feature. On the command line anywhere where you have `$SOMENAME` this is referencing an environment variable called "SOMENAME". For instance the `PATH` environment variable describes where your shell will look for programs to run.

What all this means is that this program that you have been given is expecting an environment variable called JOB_ID. You can set JOB_ID to a value and run python like so:

```
JOB_ID=my_job_id python my_python_file.py
```

If you want to put spaces in the thing you put in JOB_ID you'll have to put quotes around the value part.

With respect to python, `os.environ['ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE_NAME']` is the python way of accessing the environment variable called "ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE_NAME".

Comment: so, environment variable can only be  passed on inside of the bracket of os.enviorn like that ?

Comment: Just edited, hope that's more clear. The environment variable is not being "passed" in python, the thing inside the brackets of `os.environ` is the variable name.

Comment: Thanks. So it has nothing to do with sag ?

Comment: Only to the extent that it sounds like sag uses an environment variable with the same name (given how bland the name is, this isn't surprising).

Comment: By the way, what is the meaning of '"myoutput-{0}".format(os.environ['JOB_ID'])' ?